# Is it normal to use static members in Android widget class?

Tags: java, android, static, android-widget, android-sqlite

I have created a widget application, in which I use SQLite database object which is initialized when user enable his widget. I declare Database object as static as in other case it become `null` just after `onReceive()` method called and my application crashes.

Now I am using `mDatabase` object in `onReceive()` method and everything works except:

1. Is it normal to keep static member of Database in the Widget or there is more correct way to do that?
2. After some time of using application (one day or two) my application crashes, look like some members become null (may be `mDatabase`), I think if you answer my first question it will be answer for second too :)

---

### Code example

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static DatabaseObject mDatabase = null;
    private static int mIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        mDatabase = new DatabaseObject (context);
        mDatabase.initialize("Some data"); 
    }

    @Override
    public onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Some code ....
        mDatabase.getItemAtIndex(mIndex);
        mIndex++;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to do long lasting operations in `onReceive()`. You should start a service (`IntentService`) that updates your widget and do your DB work there. Also keep in mind that your app's activities and services can be killed at any time, so you need to handle this. If you need to access your DB helper class (`DatabaseObject`) make it a singleton and it will be available for the while lifecycle of your process.

Comment: I am not doing long lasting operations in `OnReceive()` I just get single item from database and show it on widget. So the better solution in this case is to make DatabaseObject Singleton ?

Comment: Hitting storage is considered a long lasting operation. On some devices it can take quite some time (e.g., original Samsung Galaxy). Making it a singleton should solve your original problem, yes. But do consider using a service.

Comment: And can you pleas say more about "Also keep in mind that your app's activities and services can be killed at any time, so you need to handle this." What it mean that android can stop my widget work ?

Comment: It can kill and restart your services and activities, so you should be ready to do initialization at any time. Sticking stuff in static variables once is not enough. Your original problem of 'members becoming null' after some time is probably caused by your process being restarted.

Comment: thanx a lot this is really perfect answer. +1000 for you !!! I will try to change my code and if I have questions I will write.